# Calling C# functions from IronPython

Tags: c#, ironpython

I have a a library (.dll) of C# function()s, that I want to invoke from IronPython.  An example shown here - CMD_Handshake() - is defined in a , takes no arguments, and returns a boolean...

thusly,

```
    public bool CMD_Handshake()
    {
        .
    .
    return (Send(out b_handshake_code));

    }
```

[from IronPython]

clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath() successfully adds the .dll references.

The  is successfully imported.
The class is successfully imported.
CMD_Handshake() is recognized as a method of the class
"App" is the instantiation of the class.

HOWEVER: when I invoke the function, I receive the following error message from Python:

> > > App.CMD_Handshake()
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       TypeError: CMD_Handshake() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

(I feel like I'm soooo... close.)

Comment: What is the name of the class where you declared `CMD_Handshake()`? Is it `App` or is the instance of the class called `App`?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `bool CMD_Handshake()` is an instance method and not a static one. This means you should create an instance of `App` and call the method on it:

```
app = App()
app.CMD_Handshake()
```

---

> TypeError: CMD_Handshake() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

This error is due to the fact that you are calling an instance method as a static method and thus it expects *an instance of `App`* as its first argument.

Comment: I apologize for taking so long to respond... in fact, this was precisely the case. I instantiated app = App(), and app.CMD_Handshake() return my boolean.  

Thanks, and I owe you a big coffee...